# Elasticsearch: how to apply multiple filters to the same value?

Tags: elasticsearch

Shortly: when a field has multiple values, how can I get only those items where both my filter applies to the SAME value in a multiple-values field?

### Details

I have stored in Elasticsearch some items which have a nested field with multiple values, e.g.

```
"hits": [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "tickets": [
            {
                "color": "green",
                "code": "001"
            },
            {
                "color": "red",
                "code": "002"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Frank",
        "tickets": [
            {
                "color": "red",
                "code": "001"
            },
            {
                "color": "green",
                "code": "002"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now consider these filters:

```
...
filter: [
    { terms: { 'tickets.code': '001' } },
    { terms: { 'tickets.color': 'green' } },
]
...
```

Both items match, because each one of them has at least a ticket with code "001" and each one of them has ticket with color "green".

How do I write my filters so that only the first match, because it has a ticket which has code "001" AND color "green"?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that Elasticsearch [flattens objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/nested.html#_how_arrays_of_objects_are_flattened). So internally, your data is represented something like this:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "tickets.color": ["green", "red"],
    "tickets.code": ["001", "002"]
},
{
    "name": "Frank",
    "tickets.color": ["red", "green"],
    "tickets.code": ["001", "002"]
}
```

It's impossible to know which color and code are on the same object. (The original source is also stored, in order to be returned when you make a request, but that's not the data that's queried when you search.)

There are two potential solutions here: [denormalization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/denormalization.html), or [nested data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/nested.html). If you can at all get away with it, denormalization is the better choice here, because it's more efficient. If you denormalize your data, you might end up with a representation like this:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "ticket": {
        "color": "green",
        "code": "001"
    }
},
{
    "name": "John",
    "ticket": {
        "color": "red",
        "code": "002"
    }

},
{
    "name": "Frank",
    "ticket": {
        "color": "red",
        "code": "001"
    }
},
{
    "name": , "Frank",
    "ticket": {
        "color": "green",
        "code": "002"
    }
}
```

If you use a nested data type, you'll have to use a mapping something like this:

```
{
     "ticket": {
         "type": "nested",
         "properties": {
             "color": {"type": "keyword"},
             "code": {"type": "keyword"}
         }
     }
}
```